# Encryption and Screen Lock without SIM card

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-3, encryption

I'm have a Samsung Galaxy S3 running `Android 4.1.2` which I am trying to encrypt through `Settings -> Security -> Encrypt Device`. The process I am following is described in this [article](http://reviews.cnet.co.uk/mobile-phones/how-to-make-your-samsung-galaxy-s3-more-secure-50008299/) at Step 2.

Upon entering the `Encrypt Device` screen I am told to "Set an unlock password". How is this password set? My first guess was the Android `Screen Lock`, but within `Settings -> Security` I have no `Screen` option as I would have expected (shown in above article at Step 1). Could this be because I am using the device without a SIM card? If so, is there any other way of using this encryption method, potentially with an inactive SIM card that is not connected to any network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screen lock is set in `Settings -> Screen Lock`. The device can then be encrypted without  SIM card.